# Как работает pipeline в *nix системах?

Tags: bash, unix, pipelines

Не получается правильно сформулировать проблему, поэтому на примере:

Пусть `head` работает так: выводит первые 5 строк из stdin, после чего процесс сразу завершается.

```bsh
cat some_file.txt | head -5
```

Читаем содержимое файла `some_file.txt`. Пусть в нём больше 5 строк. `head` выводит первые 5 строк и завершается.

Будет ли сам файл `some_file.txt` читаться до конца после того, как `head` вывел свои 5 строк и завершился?

Comment: Будет ли он читаться до конца, или не будет, никаким образом не зависит от работы pipeline, или от того, что там прочитает `head`. Оно зависит исключительно от реализации `cat`.

Comment: @user7860670 реализации слишком разные в разных юниксах или в чем прикол вот так отдельно упоминать реализацию cat?

Comment: @andreymal Думаю, user7860670 хотел(а) сказать, что это зависит от реализации самой программы, от которой перенаправляем stdout. В данном случае - `cat`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов вопрос к этому высказыванию тот же

Comment: А что тут непонятного? Как написано в реализации cat (или какая там программа идет в начале pipeline), так оно и будет читаться. Ничего определенного сказать нельзя.

Comment: Если что, пайп вам тут не нужен: `$ head -5 some_file.txt`.

Comment: @Ainar-G Я знаю, спасибо. Это просто для примера.

Comment: @user7860670 большинство реализаций cat имеют открытый исходный код и доступны для изучения, почему ничего определенного сказать нельзя? Совершенно непонятно, да.

Comment: @andreymal То, что большинство реализаций cat имеют открытый исходный код тут никак не поможет. Хотя бы просто потому, что никакой информации об используемой версии cat в вопросе не содержится. И вообще посыл вопроса был о том, что что-то определенное можно было бы сказать из наличия пайплайна в приведенном примере.

Comment: @user7860670 во-первых, я не думаю, что автора интересует какой-нибудь мегазакрытый проприетарный юникс, которым пользуется полтора человека — скорее всего интересует линукс или какой-нибудь BSD (а macOS использует компоненты из FreeBSD, [включая cat](https://opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-101.40.1/cat/cat.c.auto.html)). Во-вторых, я не думаю, что разные реализации cat как-то принципиально отличаются друг от друга (впрочем, я их не исследовал и могу быть не прав)

Comment: А ещё, возможно, поведение чётко описано в каком-нибудь документе POSIX и от реализации cat вообще не зависит. Но рыться в POSIX мне лень)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

когда оболочка выполняет команду вида:

```
$ программа1 | программа2
```

она запускает два процесса и загружает в них программу1 и программу2, создав предварительно временный сокет, который передаёт первому процессу в качестве *stdout*, а второму — в качестве *stdin*:

```
процесс1         процесс2
 stdout → сокет → stdin
```

если процесс2 внезапно закрывает свой *stdin* (в вашем примере — прочитав из него пять строк), то процесс1 (при попытке записи в свой *stdout*) получает сигнал `SIGPIPE`.

что именно процесс1 будет делать в таком случае — целиком и полностью зависит от того, что в него вложили разработчики программы1. как правило процесс1 тоже благополучно завершает работу.

если, как в вашем примере, процесс1 в этот момент читал информацию из файла, то вполне возможно, что к моменту получения сигнала он уже прочитал очередную «порцию» информации из этого файла. какого именно размера может быть эта «порция», зависит уже не только от реализации самой программы1, но и от операционной системы — как в ней скофигурирована буферизация того устройства, на котором размещается читаемый файл.

Comment: уточню, что `SIGPIPE` будет послан процессу1 только при попытке записать в поломавшуюся трубу, а не при завершении второго процесса. но для `cat`'а это с высокой вероятностью означает «почти сразу».

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо за уточнение. дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так на более-менее большом файле:

```
time(cat some_file.txt >/dev/null)
```

или так:

```
time(cat some_file.txt | head -5 >/dev/null)
```

Во втором случае время меньше значительно

Answer (score 0):

Файл не будет читатся до конца если не использовать излишний `cat` в таких программах как

```
head
tail
grep
awk
sed
less
ws
```

Все они могут читать файлы без посреднечества `cat`. Некоторые (сверяйтесь с документацией) могут прочесть больше однго файла за раз.

Излишняя форма

```
cat file | head -5
```

Прямой вызов

```
head -5 file
```

```
$ head --help
Usage: head [OPTION]... [FILE]... 
Print the first 10
lines of each FILE to standard output. 
With more than one FILE,
precede each with a header giving the file name.

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
```

Comment: `cat` и `head` были приведены исключительно для примера.